# How to reverse and also remove time in excel?

Tags: excel

```
29/May/18 10 : 31 AM : myUsername : Work schedule and plan is yet to be determined. May impact with current BAU activities. 

[@myUsername] to raise risk with dev.
```

What I want is to reverse & remove the time on it such that it becomes like

```
myUsername: 29/May/18 : Work schedule and plan is yet to be determined. May impact with current BAU activities. 

    [@myUsername] to raise risk with dev.
```

How to reverse and also remove time in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that text is in cell A1, you could do the following steps.  When we get to the end of the steps you can stubstitue your formulas back into the other formulas so its all in a single cell formula that is really hard to read, and therefore maintain, but will work.

Step 1) Find the First Colon

```
Cell A2
=FIND(":",A1)
```

Step 2) Find the Second Colon (or conversely the first colon after the the first colon)

```
Cell B2
=FIND(":",A1,A2+1)
```

so now you know the character where the username starts.  Now to find the character to stop at.  Find the next Colon

Step 3)  Find the third Colon

```
Cell C2
=FIND(":",A1,B2+1)
```

Step 4)  Pull the Username

```
Cell A3
=MID(A1,B2+2,C2-B2-2)
```

Step 5) Pull the date

You need to grab everything to the left of the first space

```
Cell A4
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

Step 6)  Put the items back together

```
Cell A5
=A3&": "&A4&":"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-C2)
```

Now that last bit with the RIGHT function was to strip the text down to everything after the username.  Pay attention to the spaces around the : when you put it back together.  If you wind up with too many spaces, consider wrapping step 4 and/or 5 in TRIM.  Alternatively play with the +2 and -2 in step 4 or add a -1 after the second A1 in step 5.  These numbers are controlling how many characters are pulled and what your starting pull position is.

Now to combine it all back into one ugly cell formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)+2,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)+1)-FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)-2)&": "&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))&":"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)+1))
```

[image: POC]